# bad convergence of steepest descent

Tags: numerical-optimization

Under which circumstances does the steepest descent method converge badly?

I know if the search direction is approximately perpendicular to the descent direction the steepest descent method converges slowly.

What other situations are there in which the method converges slowly and/or badly?

Comment: See [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).

Answer (score 0):

Classic example would be $$f(x, y) = \alpha x^2 + \beta y^2 $$ with $\beta \gg \alpha > 0$. Then, the contours are stretched (in $x$) ellipsoids and the steepest descent method converges slowly.